# Sum not showing correct result in Power bi Table while using DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence

I am currently learning PowerBI desktop. Here I am learning DAX formulas and measures.So, I tried to calculate sum in small data set.
My dataset is:

[image]

I tried to use the formula:

```
Average 15 year rate  for above jan2 = CALCULATE(SUM('Interest Rates'[15 year rate]),'Interest Rates'[Date]>DATE(2018,1,2))
```

I am getting sum of:

[image]

But , since I am using `'Interest Rates'[Date]>DATE(2018,1,2)` the sum I see in Excel is:

[image]

How is the sum of 8.8170 coming though the sum showing in excel is **1.082** for dates above **2018-01-02**.?

Comment: Quite unlikely happen, shorten you raw data and test it again, if it also wrong then maybe you are calculate wrong column

Comment: yes it was the mistake thank you

Comment: Glad to hear you solve it :)